# Calculate the time for progress bar is finished and throw warning if it takes too long?

Tags: c#, selenium, time, file-upload

I am automating an file upload on a web page.
The point of my automation is to check if the file upload is taking longer than expected.

This is the hmtl for the progress upload bar banner:

```
<div _ngcontent-rqo-c295="" class="upload-box-title"> 
  "Uploading List: 0/0"
  <label _ngcontent-rqo-c295="" class="ui label mini right clear-label" style="margin-right: 1px;">CLEAR</label>
</div>
```

When the process is completed, the "uploading list" text will go from "0/0" (before uploading) to "0/1" while uploading 1 file, the only case i will be testing) to "1/1" , when the upload is completed.

I have 3 questions:

- How can i check for the change in that text
- How can i get the time between "0/0" and "1/1"?
- Can i do an Assert with the time? Saying i know how long it should take when working properly and in case it takes longer it throws a warning?

Thank you for the help. I am coding in c# and Selenium. I am uploading the file with `Process.Start("\upload.exe")`. The .exe is a script done with AutoItX3.

Comment: Dont't do this `Process.Start("\upload.exe")` use `input[type='file']` CSS Selector to upload a file. you can do SendKeys for that locator. Make sure you at least should have a single element representing a input with the provided CSS.

Comment: @cruisepandey unfortunately send keys does not work as there is nowhere to put the keys in. I need to somehow select the file on the file explorer pop up. Thank you for the suggestion :)

Comment: SendKeys have the support to handle file explorer. Only thing that is required is that there should be at least one element `input[type='file']` in the upload page.

Comment: @cruisepandey i am extremely upset at not noticing the input on the html, and when i googled about AutoItx my brain just focused on it and never looked back. Just managed to upload it. Thank you very much. You know how i can close the file explorer window?

Comment: AutoIT is limited to Windows. Put some delays and it should get automatically close. try and let me know.